# Grid-Placement Issues: Grid-items in the Grid-Container wont budge

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-position, css-grid

So my issue is with the Grid Placement, for some reason the nested Paragraph elements won't allow me to align them to the grid boxes i specified.

I tried developer-tools and everything and i still cant find a logical expaination of my issue, The grid box nested in the images is the only way i can think to keep a responsive landing page and it's a pain in my butt. Could someone tell me where i went off the rails...

I tried creating a class to try " .box.grid-placement " a end selector and that didnt work either.

I'm pretty lost on this one...

Thank you for reading and taking your time to review my post.

```css
   body{
      box-sizing:border-box;
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }

    .landingPage{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 80vh;
      color:white;
    }

/*------Heres Where I've setup my grid------*/

    .box1 p,
    .box2 p,
    .box3 p {
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px 100px;
      height: 80vh;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .box1 p{
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      grid-row: 2 / 3;
    }


    /* .landingPage > div{
      width: 100%;
      height: 80vh;
    } */
    .box1{
      max-height: 100%;
    }

    .box1,
    .box2,
    .box3{
      position: relative;
    }
    .box1:after,
    .box2:after,
    .box3:after{
      content:" ";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
      bottom:0px;
      background: linear-gradient(176deg, rgba(7, 219, 131, 0.075) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.445) 57%, rgba(0, 225, 255, 0.24) 100%);
    }
    

    .box1{
      background: no-repeat center url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534146789009-76ed5060ec70?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=653&q=80");
    }
    .box2{
      background: no-repeat center url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1631339960096-b4a035ed463d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80");
    }
    .box3{
     left:0;
      background: no-repeat center url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465311354905-789ff5f7a457?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80");
    }

    .call-to-action{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 80vh;
      background: linear-gradient(176deg,rgba(130, 176, 109, 0.979) 0%, rgba(165, 91, 39, 0.966) 35%, rgba(1, 87, 99, 0.959) 100%);
      width: 100vw;
      height:19vh;
      color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="landingPage">

    <div class="box1">
      <p class='grid-placement'>Explore</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box2">
      <p>Experiance</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box3">
      <p>...and hang</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="call-to-action">
    <div class="box3--info">a</div>
    <div class="box3--info">b</div>
    <div class="box3--info">c</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: what are youy expecting by make the `p` a grid container with all those properties?

Comment: @TemaniAfif THANK TOU SO MUCH FOR THE HINT, It took a little to click but i got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First i want to thank @TemaniAfif for giving me the hint and not the answer, i took it and ran with it. I will now answer my mistake. By making the Paragraph elements Display:grid, I`ve created a grid with no grid-items. Therefore the correction is to nest the Paragraph elements into another class to make them Grid-Items.

````
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     color: white;
     font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
     height: 80vh;
     width: 100%;
   }
-------New code added to make the change of arranging the P elements----    
   .align-para-1 {
     font-size: 48px;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px 100px;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
   }


-------The Gridbox needs Items can only be moved by nesting them 
-------This code will not work to arrange the the P elements into the correct grid, so the elements must be nested. --   
   /* .box1 p,
   .box2 p,
   .box3 p {
     font-size: 48px;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px 100px;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
   } */
 
   .box1 p {
     grid-column: 2 / 3;
     grid-row: 3 / 4;
   }
   .box2 p {
     grid-column: 2 / -4;
     grid-row: 1 / 2;
   }```



  <body>
     <div class="landingPage">
       <div class="box1">
         <div class="align-para-1">
           <p>Explore</p>
         </div>
       </div>
 
       <div class="box2">
         <p>Experiance</p>
       </div>
 
       <div class="box3">
         <p>...and hang</p>
       </div>
     </div>
 
     <div class="call-to-action">
       <div class="box3--info">a</div>
       <div class="box3--info">b</div>
       <div class="box3--info">c</div>
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
````